# accessing connection variable in a while loop

Tags: php

I am trying to acces my connection variable while I run a `while` loop, yet when I try to call a function, it bogus out on me and PHP gives me the so called boolean error when I try to prepare my statement within the function.

I debugged it to the point that I know my variable `$CategorieId` is being pushed on and I do get a array return of `$con` when I do a `print_r` in the function itself. However when I try to acces it when I prepare my statement, it just returns me a `boolean`, thus creating the error in the dropdown, not being able to fill it up.

The setup is as followed.

**dbControl.php**

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','jellysite') or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));  

function OpenConnection(){
    global $con;
    if (!$con){
        die('Er kan geen verbinding met de server of met de database worden gemaakt!');
    }
}
```

**functionControl.php**

```
function dropdownBlogtypeFilledin($con,$CategorieId){
    echo "<select name='categorie' class='dropdown form-control'>";     
    $sql = "SELECT categorieId, categorieNaam 
            FROM categorie"; 
    $stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);            
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt1,$categorieId,$categorieNaam);          
    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt1)){
        echo "<option value='".$categorieId."'.";
        if( $categorieId == $CategorieId){
                echo "selected='selected'";
                }            
        echo ">".$categorieNaam."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
}
```

**Blogedit.php**

```
<?php 
require_once '../db/dbControl.php';
require_once '../db/functionControl.php';

session_start();
OpenConnection();   
$id = $_SESSION['user'];    
?>

// some html up to the while loop

<?php
        $a = $_GET['a'];
        $sql = "SELECT blog.blogId,
                       blog.blogTitel,
                       blog.blogCategorieId,
                       blog.blogSynopsis,
                       blog.blogInhoud
                FROM   blog
                WHERE  blog.blogId = ? ";
        $stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1,'i',$a);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt1, $blogId, $Titel, $CategorieId, $Synopsis, $Inhoud );

        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt1)){      
            $Synopsis = str_replace('\r\n','', $Synopsis);
            $Inhoud = str_replace('\r\n','', $Inhoud);  
    ?>

    // again some HTML

     <?php dropdownBlogtypeFilledIn($con,$CategorieId); ?>

    // guess what, more html!

<?php   
    }
?>
```

Does anyone know how I can solve it? I tried it with the global variable (the `OpenConnection()` function) but it didn't seem to work.

**Edit**

I confirm it has indeed to do with the $con variable. I tested it by defining the $con variable again in the function, and it printed perfectly what I wanted. Its a bad solutions. I just prefer to have it defined once.

The weird thing is that it happens only when i put it in a while loop. I have a create form which is exactly the same, except there is no while loop, since I create it all from scratch and there is no PHP involved on that part.  I have there a dropdown function as well, which also requires the `$con` variable, but there it works. I really think it has to do with the while loop.

Comment: Try putting `$con = mysqli_connect...` "inside" your `OpenConnection()` function or just get rid of the function altogether and just keep using your include.

Comment: Thats something I tried as well, but had no use, sadly.

Comment: I corrected it (indeed a typo in my code) and appearantly PHP is very forgiving today, since it executed the function anyway. It comes down to the fact that the `$con` variable dissapears as soon as the while loop starts. I wonder if mysqli clears out any other defined variables, or that I have to define the con variable in the while loop too.

Comment: I read a few documents about it. It only fetches the result from the prepared statement into the bound variables from `mysqli_stmt_bind_result` and checks if its `true`, `false` or `null`. It has nothign to do with that.

Comment: Ok, i read somewhere i cant use the same $con variable if i am running already a query. How do i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it for now by creating a new instance of the connection variable before i initiated the prepared statement of the page retrieving the information.

```
 <?php  
        $connection = $con;  
        $a = $_GET['a'];
        $sql = "SELECT blog.blogId,
                       blog.blogTitel,
                       blog.blogCategorieId,
                       blog.blogSynopsis,
                       blog.blogInhoud
                FROM   blog
                WHERE  blog.blogId = ? ";
        mysqli_stmt_init($con);     
        $stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1,'i',$a);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt1, $blogId, $Titel, $CategorieId, $Synopsis, $Inhoud );
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt1); 

        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt1)){      
            $Synopsis = str_replace('\r\n','', $Synopsis);
            $Inhoud = str_replace('\r\n','', $Inhoud);



       <?php dropdownBlogtypeFilledIn($connection ,$CategorieId); ?>
    ?>
```

With the variable `$connection` I could initiate the function that required the connection details within the while call. I am not sure if there is a cleaner option here, but indeed I read somewhere that I couldn't use the same connection variable if I am already using it in a prepared statement. Appearantly I cannot ride this one the same connection variable, and that seemed to be the problem. I will look into this and hope I dont have to write a while bunch of connection variables whenever I have multiple dropdowns for example that pull information from the database.